# Multiple command parameters wpf button object

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, icommand

How can I send multiple parameters from `Button` in `WPF`? I am able to send single parameter which is value of `TextBox` properly. Here is the code.

`XAML`

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,22,0,0"     Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
<Button Content="Button" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Command="{Binding Path=CommandClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=textBox1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,62,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
```

`Code behind`

```
public ICommand CommandClick { get; set; }

this.CommandClick = new DelegateCommand<object>(AddAccount);

private void AddAccount(object obj)
{
    //custom logic
}
```

Comment: if you describe what exact parameters you want, their types, and why, we might be able to help.  There is only one "binding" for a command parameter, but there are other options depending on what you need, so more info please.

Comment: You can transform many parameters in a single one, using an object[] (object array) for example, but then you need to cast all those parameters aftwerwards. Or is there a problem with that?

Comment: hi J King, it would another control . a textbox can be good assumption.

Comment: I agree with reed's answer, without knowing exactly what you need the textbox for, the best approach is to use the bound properties in the viewmodel in the command execute.  Otherwise if the textbox is part of a listbox, datagrid, combobox, etc then you could pass the selected item of the control which would give you more options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How can i send multiple parameters from button in wpf.

You can only send one parameter as the `CommandParameter`.

A better solution is typically to just bind the `TextBox` and other controls to multiple properties in your ViewModel.  The command would then have access to all of those properties (since it's in the same class), with no need for a command parameter at all.

Answer (score 34):

Other than using the approach of defining properties in you class (let's call it your ViewModel) to be binded by your view, there are times (not common) where we don't wan't to do so, an important tool to know in these situations is the MultiBinding, so just for completeness sake , even though you are satisfied with the first option, I'll cover another approach.

so to answer your question:

**1. MVVM Approach :**

Use the MVVM approach and define properties to binded by your view, and use those properties in your ViewModel's command without the need for CommandParameters.

**2. MultiBinding :** *(Can live happily with MVVM approach)*

Passing the Command Parameter as a Multi Binded parameter as seen here:

```
 <Button Content="MultiBindingExample" Command="{Binding MyCommand}">
     <Button.CommandParameter>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiConverter}">
             <Binding Path="..." ElementName="MyTextBox"/>
             <Binding Path="..." ElementName="MySomethingElse"/>
         </MultiBinding>
     </Button.CommandParameter>
 </Button>
```

With your Converter Defined using the `IMultiValueConverter` Interface:

```
public class MyMultiConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, ...)
    {
        return values.Clone();
    }
}
```

and for extracting the values: 
Simply refer to the parameter in your command as an `Object[]` and use the parameters in the same order as in the MultiBinding.

Comment: your converter returns proper values, but in the method attached to the relay command returns an array, but array elements are null.

Comment: Have you defined the static resource correctly? please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758287.aspx
for further information, focus on the stackpanel example, where you can see how to define a static resource.

Comment: I am facing same issue, everything is perfect except the values are null.

Comment: Replace return values; to return values.Clone(); in the convert of MyMultiConverter and it should work fine.