# How to use the value of textbox in mvvm commands

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I'm still figuring out mvvm and I want to make my app the right way by splitting up model viewmodel and view. In the past I always took the value of the textbox in the view directly by using mytextbox.Text.

I created a command in the viewmodel to add a new person to the network. but I can't get the values of the textboxes into the command in the viewmodel.

This is the code I have so far
in model

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Person()
    { }

    public Person(String FirstName)
    {
        this._firstName = FirstName;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _firstName;

    public string FirstName    // the Name property
    {
        get { return this._firstName; }
        set { this._firstName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName"); }
    }
}
```

in the viewmodel I have

```
public class NetworkViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _networkList1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> NetworkList1 //Binds with the listbox
    {
        get { return _networkList1; }
        set { _networkList1 = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NetworkList1"); }
    }

     public NetworkViewModel() 
    {
        AddPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(AddPerson);
    }

    private ICommand _addPersonCommand;
    public ICommand AddPersonCommand // Binding with view
    {
        get { return _addPersonCommand; }
        set { _addPersonCommand = value; }
    }

   public void AddPerson(object obj)
    {

    if(cb_group.Text.ToUpper() == "PRIMARY")
    {
        _networkList1.Add(new Person(){ FirstName = tb_firstName.Text,});
    }
}
```

in XAML

```
 <TextBox x:Name="tb_firstName"  Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
```

```
<Button x:Name="btn_add" Command="{Binding AddPersonCommand }"/>
```

What I would like is to make the value of tb_firstname and cb_group to be used in the viewmodel so I can make the command work.
Thanks for all your help. I'm just learning as I go.

Comment: Add some more context.  Where is the object (`Person`?) that `tb_firstName` is bound to?  What and where is `cb_group`?  The answer is likely to bind the values you require from the controls to properties in this ViewModel and then you have these in scope when you execute `AddPerson`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so in your textbox you currently have:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb_firstName"  Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
```

What this means is that it is looking for a property on your viewmodel called FirstName, so you will need a add a string property to your viewmodel for it. Then when you set the FirstName on the new Person, you simply set it to the property.

```
new Person() { FirstName = this.FirstName };
```

For binding a combobox, it will need an itemsSource - this is the collection of items, in your case the NetworkList1 to be shown. As its binding to a list of objects you will also need to set the DisplayMemberPath - this is the name of the property you want to be shown in the combo. 
You will also need to bind the SelectedItem property and create a property in your viewmodel to store it. This is how you know which item in your list is currently selected.

```
<Combobox ItemsSource={Binding Path=NetworkList1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
SelectedItem = {Binding Path= SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
DisplayMemberPath=FirstName/>
```

viewModel:

```
public Person SelectedPerson
{
  //put in get/set/propertychanged 
}

public string FirstName
{
   //put in get/set/propertychanged
}
```

Comment: Yep, I guess that's, better solution than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a CommandParameter and bind it to particualr Element.(in Your case tb_firstname.

Version for TextBox:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddPersonCommand } CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tb_firstname, Path=Text"/>
```

EDIT.
Version for ComboBox:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddPersonCommand } CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=yourComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Value"/> // or just SelectedItem
```

EDIT2
from ([Multiple command parameters wpf button object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952812/multiple-command-parameters-wpf-button-object))

```
<Button Content="MultiBindingExample" Command="{Binding MyCommand}">
 <Button.CommandParameter>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiConverter}">
         <Binding Path="..." ElementName="MyTextBox"/>
         <Binding Path="..." ElementName="MySomethingElse"/>
     </MultiBinding>
 </Button.CommandParameter>
```

Comment: That won't help with the need to get whatever `cb_group.Text` is, though.

Comment: Oh sorry then i didn't see that he want to pass both parameters

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is in the AddPerson method rather than looking to value in the controls(cb_group.Text) use the values those controls are bound to. The binding should by default here be 2 way. So when the user changes the value it will automatically be updated in your model/viewmodel. If this isn't happening then the problem is with your databindings and you should look to see if you have any databinding errors in your console output.