# What's name of Left MouseDoubleClick Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger

I've an `EventTrigger`:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Modify}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lv}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and it invokes the command on `MouseDoubleClick`, doesn't matter whether it's Left or Right! I want it to Invoke the command only on Left MouseDoubleClick. I've tried by chaning the `EventName` as `LeftMouseDoubleClick` and `LeftDoubleClick` but those don't work! Under the Event Section of Properties Inspector It looks like there're two `MouseDoubleClick` and `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` BUT nothing for LeftMouseDoubleClick or RighMouseDoubleClick!

Is there any such Event? If so, what's the name? 
If there's none, how such case is handled?

Answer (score 1):

You can use InputBindings to handle this. There are specific events for left double click and right double click.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                  Command="{Binding MessageCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="Left Double Click"/>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="MiddleDoubleClick"
                  Command="{Binding MessageCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="Middle Double Click"/>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightDoubleClick"
                  Command="{Binding MessageCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="Right Double Click"/>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="WheelClick"
                  Command="{Binding MessageCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="Wheel Click"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

[This is discussed in detail in this article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFMouseBindings.aspx)

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369250/listview-isnt-working-properly-with-observablecollection) case, in my `ListView` I used that `InputBindings` but it doesn't work, I don't know why! And that's the reason I've used Interaction Trigger instead of InputBindings

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in the event handler.

```
void OnMouseDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        // Left button double-click
    }
}
```

Comment: But it's an `ICommand` that only takes one argument `object o`! Can I have `MouseButtonEventArgs e` in my `ICommand`?

Comment: Yes you can use `MultiBinding` to send more than one parameter. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504958/302248

Comment: What would be `ElementName` and `Path` in `MultiBinding` list to send `MouseButtonEventArgs` to the `IMultiValueConverter` ?